# Globally available values in Blazor Server (and changing them during runtime)

Tags: blazor-server-side

In Blazor server the "appsettings.json" file is great for storing globally accessible variables. But what if these need changing during runtime? For example, lets say we have a stored value for "IsMaintenanceMode".

Given that;

1. "IsMaintenanceMode" may need to be set to "True" during runtime (to then direct users to a maintenance page)
2. If we were using a middleware to check this value for True (i.e. redirect the user to maintenance page) - then we would not want to look this variable up each time - eg from a database - on every request.

Traditionally this might have been accomplished using Application variables but I'm just not sure of the best approach with Blazor.

**So my question is - what's the best way of storing this value in a way that can be "cached" for ease of lookup, but also easily changed during runtime?**

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Look up IOptionsMonitor<T>

Comment: A Singleton Service can provide values and methods to components using Dependency Injection.  It's also very easy to do.  `Singleton` means there's only one instance running on the server, i.e. that all clients will be using the same instance.

Comment: @Mayur Ekbote, Thank you

Comment: @Bennyboy1973
 Thank you both for taking the time to reply, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StateServer.cs**

```
public class StateServer {
    public bool IsMaintenanceMode {get; set;}
}
```

Add it in **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<StateServer >();
}
```

**Component.razor** // Can be layout, main page, etc.

```
@inject StateServer _stateServer

@if (_stateServer.IsMaintenanceMode){
    <Warning />
}
else {
    <Body />
}

@code {
}
```

Or, you can check the value in one of the page lifecyle events, and navigate to whatever page you like.